# Two view controllers inside one view controller, managing the frame property

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, cgrect

I would like to have to have an iAd banner load inside an app at the bottom of the window, and have the rest of the app, the UINavigationController and view be on the top part of the window.  I've experimented and tried to use my math and logic skills but can't seem to get the them to appear correctly.

The iAd banner is displayed in the correct location, but the NavigationController is not.

```
//AppDelegate.h
AdViewController *adController;
UINavigationController *navController;
UIViewController *containerView;

//.m file didFinishLaunching...
//views and controllers already initialized
containerView.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
[containerView.view addSubview self.adController.view];
[containerView.view addSubview self.navController.view];

//hard coded frame for an ADBannerView (loaded in .xib)
CGRect bannerFrame = self.adController.view.frame;

//sets the start point vertically by subtracting the 
//banner height from the total height of the screen
//in this case, 480 - 50
bannerFrame.origin.y = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height - bannerFrame.size.height;

self.adController.view.frame = bannerFrame;

//returns a rectangle that takes the 20 px status bar into account
//this rectangle's y origin is at 20
CGRect appFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame];

//This CGRect is assuming the applicationFrame
CGRect navFrame = appFrame;

//subtract the banner height from the navFrame height
//takes 50 px off of the height
navFrame.size.height = navFrame.size.height - bannerFrame.size.height;

self.navController.view.frame = navFrame;
```

[image: iOS Simulator]

Answer (score 0):

iAd banners need a viewcontroller. Further, Apple say that a viewcontroller should control a whole screens worth of views - until we can write our own container views in ios5.

I suggest you check out Apple' demo iAd code, particularly AdBannerNavigation.app.

Another option may be using the mobClix framework, with that you can add an iAd banner to a navigation controller.

I assume you are planning for when there are no ads to show? as sometimes fill-rates can be low.

p.s. have you tried adding and sizing the navigation controller before adding the bannerview?